# apply-templates for only specific elements in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have an inout and I want apply template for only specific elements.

Input:

```
<p>patagaram 1<italic>weas</italic>(<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R3"><italic>3</italic></xref>) (<xref ref-type="fig" rid="F1">Figures 1</xref> and <xref ref-type="fig" rid="F2">2</xref>).</p>
```

Tried code:

```
<p type="{$type}">
        <xsl:if test="$id">
            <xsl:attribute name="id" select="$id"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
```

What I want:

I want to apply template except `xref[@ref-type='fig']` which is inside `p`. How can I do this.

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please edit your post so it contains information about what the issue is you're facing. for example include any errors you are encountering, or what the current (unexpected) behavior is.

Comment: Please check:-


<xsl:template match="p/xref "/>

Comment: What would be the result you want? It looks like you just want to by pass some `xref` element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not obvious what your intention is.

If you want to exclude the  element from the output, an empty template as @Ajeet Singh proposes, would be the solution.

In XSLT a template rule applies only to the contents of its @match attribute.

If you want to define a kind of global template that applies to all elements except xref inside p, you could also write:

`<xsl:template match="*[not(self::xref[parent::p])]">
       ** do something **
 </xsl:template>`